# Nginx config for Angular 4 CLI app

Tags: angular, nginx, webserver, angular-cli, nginx-location

I've been digging through stackoverflow-answers and github issues for hours, however I could not yet find a proper solution for this.

I have an Angular 4 application built with the Angular-CLI. 
I want to serve this application from an nginx server (inside a Docker container) at `http://XYZ:80/angularapp`.

In order to have this application-wide base-href I built the app using `ng build --base-href /angularapp` which adds `<base href="/angularapp">` to my `index.html` in the `dist` folder.

For the deployment I have copied the contents of `dist` to `/usr/share/nginx/html` and my nginx config looks as follows:

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;

    location /api {
        # adjust port of backend to desired port
        proxy_pass http://backend:8081;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
    }

    location / {
        root  /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html$is_args$args;
    }
}
```

This works absolutely fine and I can access the app by going to `http://XYZ:80/angularapp` or `http://XYZ:80/` (will redirect to `/angularapp`).

Now I tried to link this app from a different domain (e.g. `http://my-intranet/app`) which should also show the contents of `http://XYZ:80/angularapp`. 
However, this is causing an issue as all the assets have the wrong request paths (e.g. `http://my-intranet/main.f574d09ce6036fc0840e.bundle.js`). Thus, I get an error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <`.

I tried using the `--deploy-url /angularapp` and `--deploy-url .`, that breaks the original app url (`http://XYZ:80/angularapp`).

Can someone provide help on how to properly configure the nginx locations for this case? Thank you in advance!

Comment: try this `ng build --prod --base-href .` , it will work for every domain

Comment: How would I have to set the location in the nginx config then in order to have the app running at `http://XYZ:80/angularapp` rather than `http://XYZ:80` ?

Comment: When you say I tried to link `http://my-intranet/app` to this app. How did you establish this link?

Comment: Unfortunately, as this DNS mapping is done by an external provider I don't have any insights into that process.

Comment: Did you get to the bottom of this? If yes how, mind sharing please? I am faced with the same issue

Answer (score 2):

When you are using `try_files` directive of nginx along with the `--base-href` in angular-cli. it creates a problem.

As when nginx traverses your index.html and sees the link for styles.xxx.bundle.css, inline.xxx.bunble.js, and various other bundles.

As `--base-href` appends /angularapp/styles.xxx.bundle.css and /angularapp/inline.xxx.bunble.js to the link and nginx tries the location block and `try_files` directive is executed to redirect the URI to index.html.

That is why you see the

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

To avoid this you should use `--deploy-url` and make the folder path with same name as the `--base-href` and `--deploy-url` such as /usr/share/nginx/html/angularapp/ and copy the dist folder there.

Then the app would work otherwise removing `try_files` or don't use `--base-href`